# Is it better to split functions into different files?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php file to handle a big amount of MySQL queries for my site and I'm expecting about hundreds to thousands users using it at a time. Will it make difference for the server reaction speed if I keep all these functions as a single file, or should I split them?

Comment: It won't make a lot of difference, to be honest. I'd be more inclined to check that you're running an accelerator and something like FastCGI or fcgid, so that PHP processes stay in memory.

Comment: Split them to be grouped and organized logically, don't worry about site performance impact until you notice a problem that needs optimizing.

Comment: Also, your database is a huge possible source for optimisation. Check your indexes are up to scratch.

Comment: Split them, maintenance will be a far bigger problem, especially if you want to optimise.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a highly frequented web page, you should organize your code perfectly, because it seems to be more than a guestbook page - otherwise, the project runs out of your control. So put each function into its own file!

Only your second thought should be about performance. You could think about using opcode cache or other improvements like a static-map autoloader, a build script, that merges your php files and stuff.

But don't start to ruin your project's source code with this bad style.

Comment: I'm a huge fan of AJAX, so there is nothing this file does, except for returning some value (or not) for some AJAX request. Some of the functions are so small, writing an "include" for the is longer than the function itself.

Comment: I'm no fan of AJAX.B ut yes, organizing your code in a good manner is key! And why using include? Use autoloading.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting functions into different files more better than writing all functions in one file 

it's make including files more faster and best performance .... because you include only functions you want also you save server memory .
Also it's make you code more readable .

Comment: The problem is some functions can call other functions dynamically, so there's no real profit for splitting them. They all need to be included anyway.

Comment: great , in this case you can group all related functions together in one file ... instead of including unwanted functions